# I am getting an error when redeploying the Mule Api on my local anypoint studio or you can say local machine

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mule4

when I deploy a Mule API and after deployment, I do some changes and save it then my API gets redeploy.
during redeployment, I am getting the below error in the console that stops the deployment.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
Dumping heap to java_pid19656.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [197920637 bytes in 0.811 secs]
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="taskkill /F /PID %p"
#   Executing "taskkill /F /PID 19656"...
JVM exited unexpectedly.
Automatic JVM Restarts disabled.  Shutting down.
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

anyone can help me to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are having a known issue related to r[edeployments that cause the metaspace are to get exhausted](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/java-lang-OutOfMemoryError-Metaspace-when-Deploying-Applications-to-Mule-4-Runtime). It is recommended to use the latest version of Mule and the latest version of every connector used in your applications to mitigate that issue.

Also ensure that the MetaspaceSize is half of MaxMetaspaceSize. You can increase MaxMetaspaceSize if you feel you are deploying lots of classes or applications, but keep the proportion mentioned.

```
wrapper.java.additional.7=-XX:MetaspaceSize=128m
wrapper.java.additional.8=-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
```

Comment: hello @aled, where do we need to add this configuration.

Comment: Hello @aled, It did not help me. any other solution?

Comment: What's the Mule version, and have you applied the last cumulative patch for your version?